# react-native run-ios: The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined

Tags: ios, react-native

I am playing with React-Native and trying to build a Hello-world app, however, I am still unable to run the app. If I run `react-native run-ios`, I get this error:
...

```
Build system information
unexpected service error: The Xcode build system has crashed. Please close and reopen your workspace.

Build system information
error: unexpected service error: The Xcode build system has crashed. Please close and reopen your workspace.


** BUILD FAILED **


The following commands produced analyzer issues:
    Analyze /Users/adam/react-native_dev/JustATributeApp/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTModuleMethod.mm normal x86_64

(1 command with analyzer issues)

The following build commands failed:
    Analyze /Users/adam/react-native_dev/JustATributeApp/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text/RCTTextAttributes.m normal x86_64
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JustATributeApp.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JustATributeApp.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

I found quite a few topics with this error, but none of them led to solving it.

Here is some additional information:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.56.0
xcode 10.0 beta 2 (10L177m)
```

How do I debug/fix this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The key piece of the error message is `Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.` Here's how we can fix that.
Open yourprojectname.xcodeproj in Xcode, and check the bundle identifier under the 'General' tab. It should have a value. Mine is com.yourprojectname.app.ios.triplets . If that field is blank, set the bundle identifier to something. Modifying this field will make the changes to your info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest restarting React.

To do so, just run the following commands:

```
# Kill current processes
killall node -9 

# Start React - Native
react-native start 

# Run android
react-native run-android or react-native run-ios
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: I think you meant `run-ios`.

Comment: yes,i have edited my answer. For android react-native run-android and for ios  react-native run-ios